# How can I manually trigger a codebuild in aws console with a submodule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have a codebuild project which is triggered from bitbucket repository. The repository has a git submodule. In my buildspec file I have this config and "build_ssh_key" includes the repository ssh key. The codebuild project is running fine if it is triggered by webhook from bitbucket. But when I run the codebuild project manually from AWS console, I see an error

"Submodule error error creating SSH agent: "SSH agent requested but SSH_AUTH_SOCK not-specified" for primary source and source version develop
"
The project failed in down source project.Could you let me know why it fails when I manually trigger it?

```
buildspec.yml:

version: 0.2

env:
  parameter-store:
    build_ssh_key: "build_ssh_key"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting because [source](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=301019):

> The submodules must be configured as https and not ssh.

Depending on your setup you can consider  [Changing Git Submodule Repository to other URL/Branch](https://tech.serhatteker.com/post/2019-01/changing-git-submodules-urlbranch-to/)

There is a another [thorough answer to configure codebuild with submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64163023/2246345) you might wanna check.